# Terraform fails to create Azure Container Instance because the image is inaccessible

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-instances

In my main.tf I have the following resource;

```
resource "azurerm_container_group" "auth_container_group" {
  name                = "foocg"
  location            = "UK South"
  resource_group_name = "foorg"

  ip_address_type = "public"
  dns_name_label  = "fooapi"
  os_type         = "Linux"

  image_registry_credential {
    username = "foo"
    password = "notMyRealPassword"
    server   = "foo.azurecr.io"
  }

  container {
    name   = "foo"
    image  = "foo:${var.imagebuild}" //also tried "foo.azurecr.io/foo:${var.imagebuild}"
    cpu    = "1"
    memory = "1"

    ports {
      port     = 80
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
  }
}
```

I have built a CD pipeline in Azure Devops. If I use a public image repository the resource is created and I can view my api, the build succeeds. As soon as I swap to a private repository I get the following error in the pipeline output log;

> Error: creating/updating Container Group: (Name "foocg" / Resource
> Group "foorg"):
> containerinstance.ContainerGroupsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure
> sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error:
> Code="InaccessibleImage" Message="The image 'foo:417' in container
> group 'foocg' is not accessible. Please check the image and
> registry credential.

I have tried using a private docker hub registry, and an Azure Container registry, the latter I have enabled admin user in order to get the login details.

Could anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong and what I might do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested in my enviorment with your code and was getting the same error.

[image]

***To resolve the issue use the below code ( did changes in your code at `images Section`)***

***`main.tf`***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "X-raXXXX-XXX"
}

resource "azurerm_container_group" "auth_container_group" {
  name                = "containergroupfooog"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_address_type = "public"
  dns_name_label  = "aci-label798"
  os_type         = "Linux"

  image_registry_credential {
    username = "TestMyAcr90"
    password = "OFfxXXXXXXXXX351XXhl6"
    server   = "testmyacr90.azurecr.io"
  }

  container {
    name   = "sidecar"
    image  = "${var.imagebuild}" 
    cpu    = "1"
    memory = "1"
    ports {
      port     = 80
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
  }
  
}
```

***`variable.tf`***

```
variable "imagebuild" {
  description = "Repository"
  default = "testmyacr90.azurecr.io/my_nginx:latest"
}
```

[image]

**`Output--`**

[image]

[image]
[image]